# Generating Excel Documents from XML

Tags: xml, excel, xls

In my build automation, I have a NAnt task that uses C# Linq2XML and an Office Interop library to generate an Excel (.xls ) document based on an input XML file.  We also have a similar process that uses a xslt to generate an HTML page.

I can't help think I'm reinventing the wheel.   Can anyone suggest a program/library that basically acts like a transformation engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it have to be XLS?  or can it be XLSX? Because XLSX is just zipped XML.  Unzip it and see the directory structure of xml files.  You can create one by writing XML files and zipping them.